# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Need to prove:

> If $f$ is a real-valued function defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},|f(x)|\leq x^2$ then $f$ is differentiable at $0$

I couldn’t find any leads, help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition of the derivative?

Comment: @Arthur I have tried both the $h$ definition and $x-x_0$ definition, neither of which worked for me :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we have $|f(0)|\leq0^2$ so $f(0)=0$.Now we can see that $|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}|\leq|x|\Rightarrow -x\leq\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\leq x\Rightarrow\lim_{x \to0}{\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}}=0$ so $f'(0)=0$

Comment: How did you get that it implies that the limit is 0?

Comment: I added one more step to my solution.Is it clear now?(I just apply the Squeeze theorem)

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

$$ |f(0)| \leq 0^2 \Rightarrow f(0)=0$$

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^*$.

$$ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

and

$$ \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| \leq \left|\frac{x^2}{x}\right| \leq |x|$$

Now, can you find the limit of the $\frac{f(x)}{x}$?